# how to write comments/documentation for Django methods/classes

Tags: django

I am quite new with Django, and I was wondering if I could document my methods or classes.
In C# you would have somthing like

```
 ///
 <summary>
 this is my method xy
 </summary
 public void xy(){
 }
```

How do I document or describe methods in Django?
I have seen something like

```
def xy(self):
   """ this is my method xy """
```

but when I use this in my django code, I get an error.

**EDIT:** Strange. After some uncommenting in settings.py, there is no more error.
When i use Aptana3 (IDE for python) and start typing in the method **xy** i see the description **this is my method xy** and that is ok.

But is there no intern Django feature to print all those documented Classes and methods to a html file?

And where do I see the documentation? Only IDE with autocompletion or is django collectin all the descriptions of my methods and showing them in a html, placed within my django project?

Comment: What do you mean you get an error? Did you add a `pass` statement at the end of `def xy` or did you just enter the docstring without a `pass` statement?

Comment: Also can you please add the error message to your question?

Comment: i think the error occured, because i had commented some lines of code in settings.py. Now the error is gone, but stil i would like to see all my documented classes and methods in some kind of html or xml format as documentation.

Comment: If you want HTML/PDF output, Sphinx is definitely the way to go. See @arie's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good choice for documenting your Django project is [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/).

With Sphinx you can generate docs in multiple formats (HTML, PDF, LaTeX, etc.)
and the [autodoc extension](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute) lets you easily document your methods and attributes.